# If a ring is not an integral domain does it then implies that it is not a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I have some problems in understanding the relation between domains.

> As I understood it I know that we have the following implications PID$\Rightarrow$UFD$\Rightarrow$integrally closed domain$\Rightarrow$integral domain.

Now my confusion arises if I consider the following example. Let us take $R:=\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}$. This is not an integral domain since for example $\bar 2\cdot \bar 3=\bar 6=\bar 0$ but $\bar 2, \bar 3\neq \bar 0$. But then using the above implications I would get that $R$ is not a PID. As I understood it, by definition this means that there are ideals which are not generated by a single element of $R$.  But on the  other side I have seen the remark that ideals in $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ are of the form $(\bar m)$ for $\bar m \in \Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$.

Where is my mistake?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137070/discussion-on-question-by-wave-if-a-ring-is-not-an-integral-domain-does-it-then).

Comment: I'd like to note that I consider this a good example of a well written "where is my mistake" question.  The user has provided enough context about what they think ought to be and how it clashes with what they observe to decisively say what the misconception is, and it seems very possible that another person may follow the same line of thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation of "is a domain and all its ideals are principal" is not "it is not a domain AND it has nonprincipal ideals."

The negation would be "It is not a domain OR it has a nonprincipal ideal (possibly both.)"

You have an example of a principal ideal **ring** that isn't a domain.

Also,  $\mathbb Z[x]$ is a domain with nonprincipal ideals.

Finally, $\mathbb Z[x]\times\mathbb Z$ is not a domain and also has a nonprincipal ideal.

All three are examples of rings that aren't PIDs.

Comment: DaRT queries: [Domains which aren't PIDs](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=8&L=65l), [PIR's which aren't domains](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=66l&L=8), and [rings which are neither PIR's nor domains](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&L=8&L=66l)